How do I create an NVIDIA OptiX project in Visual Studio?
I am deciding to make a realtime ray tracer using OptiX (was initially planning on using CUDA but it seems like OptiX is easier to learn due to abstractions). It seems like I can't find any resources about this.
I have tried adding additional library and include dependencies of both CUDA and OptiX directories and have added cuda.lib and cudart.lib to Additional dependencies section in the project properties. Even after all that executing the project results in error as shown in the image.
Or if you want to see the error in text form:
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Details
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol g_optixFunctionTable Realtime Ray tracer C:\Users\aahad\Documents\Computer Science\GitHub\Procedural-World-Gen-with-Ray-Tracing\Realtime Ray tracer\Realtime Ray tracer\main.obj 1       

I have also seen about the CMake build method but I have no clue what I'm looking at.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
